# looping through XML file using VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing

I am having a problem processing an XMl file. I want to loop through (using VB.NET) the file and extract all the values of the OrderID element.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ListOrdersResponse xmlns="https://xxx.xxxxxx.com/Orders/999uuu777">
  <ListOrdersResult>
    <NextToken>XXXXXXXXXX</NextToken>
    <Orders>
      <Order>
        <ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>Standard</ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>
        <OrderId>ooooooooo</OrderId>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>Standard</ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>
        <OrderId>ujuujujuj</OrderId>
      </Order>
      </Orders>
    <CreatedBefore>2013-06-19T09:10:47Z</CreatedBefore>
  </ListOrdersResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>8e34f7d9-3af7-4490-801b-cccc7777yu</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</ListOrdersResponse>
```

Here is the code I am trying but it does not loop through each order

```vb
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(file)
Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes(".//Orders/Order")
For Each node As XmlElement In nodelist
   console.writeline(node.SelectSingleNode("OrderID").InnerText)
Next
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
doc.Load(file)
nodelist = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Order")

For Each node As XmlElement In nodelist
   Console.Writeline(node("OrderID").InnerText)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

The xPath expression I run that gets both orders is `//tns:Order`

```vb
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(file)
Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//tns:Order")
For Each node As XmlElement In nodelist
  '2 exist
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I replace ".//Orders/Order" with "//tns:Order" I get an exception. Can you explain what the //tns: path is?

Comment: Sorry forgot to attach the exception. It is Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

Comment: @user2516387 - `tns` is just the xml namespace alias that DonA used when creating a sample program. You can remove that.

Comment: if I use "//Order" it fails to process the for...next loop it ie. returns 0 nodes.

Comment: That's the path LiquidXML came up with. I thought it was odd, since I remembered using `//Order` in the past.